# What word did Brienne scream out?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

At the end of [A Feast for Crows, Chapter 42](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Feast_for_Crows-Chapter_42), Brienne and her group are

> hanged by the Brotherhood Without Banners.

But then

> she screamed a word. Apparently this saved her, since we see her again in the next book.

What was that word?

Comment: speculation, but "Sapphires!" - it worked before so why not.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Miscon_Report), GRRM confirmed:

> the word brienne screamed was “sword”; lady stoneheart gave brienne the choice of either swearing her sword to her or being hung, saying “sword or noose”, and as brienne was being hung she screamed “sword”

This can be inferred from the text, since as George said, Brienne was given the choice of two words in AFFC. And we

> See her later on in ADWD, implying she said the word Lady Stoneheart wanted to hear.

Answer (score 2):

We do not find out that word in A Dance With Dragons.

From [A Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brienne):

> A Feast For Crows: Brienne refuses to choose and is sentenced to hang. After seeing Podrick Payne hanging near her, she shouts a single **unknown word** as they are about to do the same to her.
>
> A Dance With Dragons: Brienne appears briefly at Pennytree when Jaime camps there, **whatever word she shouted** apparently making the Brotherhood spare her.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question

Comment: How does it not answer the question? The word isn't revealed.

Answer (score 1):

She shouts 'sword'. She was given a choice of being Lady Stoneheart's 'sword' and going to get Jaime for her, or of dying by the 'noose'. She shouts sword which is what saves her - and saves Podrick. George explained this to an audience at a recent chat.

Comment: Can you give us a link to George's explanation?

Comment: [Here](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Miscon_Report) is the link (same as in previous answer), from 2012 MISCON.

Answer (score -4):

the word is a name - Arya. Catelyn thinks Arya dead and so did most everyone else. The Elder Brother on the Silent Isle shocked Brienne with his news. Brienne was in bad shape and shocked by Lady Catelyn's appearance and that forestalled her sharing that information but the prospect of imminent death tends to sharpen the senses.

Comment: Not a bad speculation; but in comparison to the non-speculative and accepted answer, this is redundant.

Comment: Interesting idea especially with respect to the show, but there is zero evidence for this in the books...